# No cmp keyword for max function in python

Tags: python, max, cmp

So, when sorting a list in python, the `sorted` function can take a `cmp` keyword to override the `__cmp__` function of the objects we are sorting.

I would expect `max` to have a similar keyword, but it doesn't. People know why?

And in any case, anyone know the most pythonic way to get around this? I don't want to override `__cmp__` for the classes themselves, and other options I can think of like `sorted(L,cmp=compare)[0]` seem ugly. What would be a nice way to do this?

The actual example is given as `L=[a1,a2,...,an]` where each `ak` is itself a list of integers we want the maximum where `ai<aj` is in the lexicographical sense.

Comment: Python's default behaviour is to compare lists lexicographically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `cmp`. It has been removed from Python3 in favor of `key`.

Since Python compares strings lexicographically, you could use `key = str` to find the "maximum" integer:

```
In [2]: max([10,9], key = str)
Out[2]: 9
```

Comment: Ah, now that you've mentioned it, I see? So I can use `functools.cmp_to_key` with my comparison function for `max` and `sorted`